# regular expression problem $(A \cup B)^∗AB(A \cup B)^∗ \cup B^∗A^∗ = (A \cup B)^∗$

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

can anybody prove the statement below using only basic identities?
$A$ and $B$ are disjoint languages.
$$(A \cup B)^∗AB(A \cup B)^∗ \cup B^∗A^∗ = (A \cup B)^∗$$